# firebase Deep collectionGroup query in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, firebase-tools

I have a collection structure in Firestore that looks like:

```
/teams/**/days/**/milestones/**
/teams/1WCraAZXLSNSoMvkZuSV/days/20210822/milestones/xyzdocid
```

So, I would have a set of documents in the milestones collection at the end.  I'm trying to query milestones as a collectiongroup.  How do I setup a collectionGroup index for this?

Is this too deep for the collectionGroup to work?  What does the index look like for this?  Is it possbile to create this collectionGroup index in the firebase emulator?

Comment: This all looks quite feasible to me. A collection group is not dependent on depth, but purely on the name of the collections, which is the same in both subcollection here. Did you try creating the necessary index already? What problem did you run in to?

Comment: You say *I'm trying to query milestones as a collectiongroup.*. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Two problems: 1.  I can’t figure out how to create an index in the emulator. Do I have to do this in the live console only?  2. I can’t figure out how to create an index on the milestones sub collection. All the documentation assume 1 level deep sub collections. The ‘create exemption’ area in the live console doesn’t allow me to specify a deep path to this subcollection. Somehow I need to say that the index should be on children/days/milestones. None of the fields allow a path.

Comment: Thanks Frank, even though you said it based on the name only, it didn't click with me for a while.  Completely new concept to be able to query across collections, documents and at any path / level.

Answer (score 1):

To anybody running into this same problem:

1. In the Emulator, collectionGroups and all index related operations automatically work.  You don't need to setup anything special.  This wasn't very well documented.  I spent quite some time trying to find out how to create an index in the emulator.  This also means, that you will need to do quite a bit of testing with a live firebase account, because most things will not automatically work there.
2. The collectionGroup format is based on the name of the collection only and not your indexes or any kind of paths.  Meaning, if you have collections called "milestones" anywhere in your structure, the collectionGroup concept will combine them together.  This is very powerful, but be careful about collections / subCollections with the same name but different purpose.